# Hibernate exception JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, websphere

Hibernate 4 webapp with Spring 4.  In Rational Application Developer (IBM's flavor of eclipse) and WebSphere.  Our app is being upgraded for spring and hibernate.

The following exception occur on startup:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.processComplementaryTableDefinitions(EntityBinder.java:936)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:781)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3762)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3716)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1410)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:339)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:427)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 77 more
```

The following info may or may not be related.  I think it is.

Awhile back, a co-worker solved an error by putting the hibernate JPA 2.0 api jar in our IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\java\jre\lib\ext folder.  He said that this was needed because RAD or WAS had an older JPA and we needed 2.0 to get loaded before it.  This seemed like a bad answer at the time, and now we definitely know it was because as we upgrade our apps one at a time to use Hibernate 4, we need 2.1.  But we can't have BOTH in that folder together.

How then should one deal with this second problem, and I am wondering if folks think this is related to the first problem, and how to solve both.

Answer (score 0):

JPA library might be placed into `WEB-INF\libs` webapp directory.
But for WebSphere Application Server exists special JPA2 feature pack: [WebSphere Application Server V7 Feature Pack for OSGi Applications and Java Persistence API 2.0](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/osgi/)